# Replacement of terms and formulas

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to study mathematical logic with J.R.Shoenfield's *Mathematical Logic*.

Section 3.4 starts with the **Equivalence Theorem**, which states the following ($A, B, ...$ denote formulas of a first order language).

> Let $A'$ be obtained from $A$ by replacing some occurrences of $B_1, ..., B_n$ by $B_1', ..., B_n'$ respectively. If $\vdash B_1\leftrightarrow B_1', ..., \vdash B_n\leftrightarrow B_n'$, then $\vdash A\leftrightarrow A'$.

My question is **how exactly do we replace $B_1, ..., B_n$ by $B_1', ..., B_n'$?** I believe that from the occurrence theorem $B_i$ and $B_j$ are either distinct or one is a part of the other. I'm interested in the latter case. The proof seems to work for any reasonable way of defining the *replacement* but then the theorem states very different things for each such way; or is that intended?

I have the same question about replacing terms by terms inside of terms and formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what you mean:

If $A$ is $(\phi_1 \land \phi_2) \to \phi_3$, and we have $\vdash (\phi_1 \land \phi_2) \leftrightarrow \phi_4$ and $\vdash \phi_1 \leftrightarrow \phi_5$, then what is the result of the 'replacing'?

Once we replace $\phi_1 \land \phi_2$ with $\phi_4$, we are left with $\phi_4 \to \phi_3$, and so we can no longer apply the $\vdash \phi_1 \leftrightarrow \phi_5$ equivalence.

On the other hand, if we start with the latter equivalence, we end up with $(\phi_5 \land \phi_2) \to \phi_3$, and now we can't apply the first equivalence. That is, the replacements are 'interfering' with each other.

So, is $A'$ supposed to be $\phi_4 \to \phi_3$ or $(\phi_5 \land \phi_2) \to \phi_3$?  It doesn't seem well-defined.

I think the key is that the book says 'some':

> Let $A'$ be obtained from $A$ by replacing **some** occurrences of $B_1, ..., B_n$ by $B_1', ..., B_n'$ respectively. if $\vdash B_1\leftrightarrow B_1', ..., \vdash B_n\leftrightarrow B_n'$, then $\vdash A\leftrightarrow A'$.

That is, the book does not force every replacement to take place, even if more can take place.  As such, $A'$ is not the *unique* result of making any such replacements, but can be one of many.  For example, even if $A$ is $(\phi_1 \land \phi_2) \to \phi_1$, and we have $\vdash \phi_1 \leftrightarrow \phi_3$ and $\vdash \phi_2 \leftrightarrow \phi_4$ (so we can apply all equivalences without any 'interference') then $A'$ can still be one of many possible outcomes:

$(\phi_3 \land \phi_4) \to \phi_3$

or

$(\phi_3 \land \phi_2) \to \phi_3$

or

$(\phi_3 \land \phi_4) \to \phi_1$

or

$(\phi_3 \land \phi_2) \to \phi_1$

or

$(\phi_1 \land \phi_4) \to \phi_3$

or

$(\phi_1 \land \phi_2) \to \phi_3$

or

$(\phi_1 \land \phi_4) \to \phi_1$

or even simply the original

$(\phi_1 \land \phi_2) \to \phi_1$

However, whichever one you take, they are all equivalent to the original.

With that, I don't think there is any issue here.  But, I will say that the theorem could have avoided any confusion by simply doing:

> Let $A'$ be obtained from $A$ by replacing some occurrences of $B$ by $B'$ respectively. if $\vdash B\leftrightarrow B'$, then $\vdash A\leftrightarrow A'$.

This, of course has the same effect, since if you want to apply other equivalences, you can just reapply this theorem.